# Error in LWC file upload component in community

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-community, community-builder

We are having a LWC file upload component and using that LWC in community page and here is the code

```
<template>
  <lightning-file-upload
        label="Upload files"
        name="fileUploader"
        accept={acceptedFormats}
        record-id={accountId}
        onuploadfinished={handleUploadFinished}
        multiple>
  </lightning-file-upload>
</template>
```

After clicking the upload button getting below Javascript error

[image]

This issue is happening only in community.

PS:Have enabled the **Allow site guest users to upload files** under salesforce files in setup

Answer (score 0):

`lightning-file-upload` is not currently supported in LWR communities, [as documented here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.exp_cloud_lwr.meta/exp_cloud_lwr/get_started_comp_limitations.htm). You can use it with other community templates though.